# import a yii package to the project

Tags: yii, netbeans-7, yii-extensions

I tried to work with `CPasswordHelper` and everytime I got an `exception` when trying to run one of its methods. I think the reason is that I didn't import the `package`(`system.utils`) that `CPasswordHelper` is belong to. My question is how do I do that?
If it matter I'm working with `netBeans`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CPasswordHelper` is a core class defined in YiiBase, you don't need import it before using.

It is added since 1.1.14, may be you should check your yii version.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. I'm working on 1.1.13 :(.
Any chance its simple to upgrade?

Comment: you can follow this to update http://static.yiiframework.com/files/UPGRADE-1.1.14.txt